# Why am I getting ORA-01843 error on Toad-Oracle when trying to import a table with timestamp data, and how to fix it?

Tags: oracle, import, toad

I'm trying to import a table to Toad- oracle and I created the table like this
create table Merchants_Actions (
merchant_id varchar(50),   service_code  varchar(50) , action_date timestamp ,    trx_amount number,   balance_after number,   balance_before  number,  action_type_code varchar(50))

and the shape of action_date values are like :2023-02-05 10:15:10.975

when I'm trying to proceed in the import process it gives me this error : "ORA-01843: not a valid month"

So what could be the error and how to solve it ?

I tried to change the datatype of the column, but I was getting the same error
I'm thinking to alter the table to make the datatype to be char instead of date, Is that right
and what could be the most best solution for this case ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to explain your import process. On one level you might be able to change your NLS settings, but if you're using insert statements you should specify the format via `to_timestamp()`; if if you're using a Toad command/wizard then you may need to specify the target data type (and/or NLS) as part of that.

Comment: Yes, I'm inserting data using Toad 

from Database menu --> Import --> import table data

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have found where was the problem i didn't take the delimiter in date in consideration